# strings.xml disappearing from my eclipse workspace

Tags: android, eclipse

I saw strings.xml vanish from my values/ directory before my eyes when I saved another file.

I tried manually making a new strings.xml (New -> File) but it got disappeared, too.

What's making it disappear?  Is there a log that shows all the magical things that Eclipse is doing under the hood?

**EDIT** Answer: values/ had moved from res/values/ to values/.  How?  I haven't the slightest. But when I made a new directory of values under res/, I could make a new Android XML file under there, and then populate it.

Comment: Please read the Dev guide:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html

Comment: Did you accidentally drag/drop the folder?  I've done this before and find that on a laptop with a trackpad it's even easier to do accidentally than with a mouse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There can be a few things - the first thing to try is switch to Resource view.

Regardless of what view, you can click the down arrow at the top right of the folder tab/window thing and you can configure filers.  Make sure it doesn't have that file filtered for some reason.